# function call returns NaN when all types are correct

Tags: java, types, int, double, nan

A function call keeps returning NaN, when taken out of context it works but in context it doesn't

I've tried changing types between double and Double to no avail

```
private Double average(ArrayList<Double> x){
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        sum += x.get(i);
    return sum / x.size();
}
```

the return is NaN in most cases

Comment: What is the context? Is `x` empty? And what are most cases? Please be more specific.

Comment: Show us an example of input giving NaN output when it shouldn't.

Comment: Even if `x` is never supposed to be empty, "in context" there might be an error somewhere else that is making it empty.

Comment: Is it possible you produce a division by zero if the arraylist is empty?

Answer (score 2):

The only root cause is the division for sure. that is `x.size()` is 0. Please check it before divide really happens to prevent it.